# Thunderbird message filters, use OR

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to use OR in message filters?

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Not that I'm any expert at boolean logic, but isn't that the same as having two entries, one for WordOne & another for WordTwo?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the OR function, you just cant use it in a single entry.

Just make sure you have the "match any of the following" option selected and then enter each term on separate line entries using the "+" icon on the right.

[image]

"Match all" is equivalent to "Must contain all the following" which means a logical AND function.

"Match any" is equivalent to "Must contain at least one or more of the following" which means a logical OR function.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to keep it in one line; reason is that I have a list of hundreds of words, so it would be easy to just copy-paste into one line.

Comment: Sadly that's not how the UI is set up to work. You might be able to find your `msgFilerRules.dat` file and see if it is editable to add your rules in the way you want, some info on it can be found at https://kb.mozillazine.org/Message_Filters. That page has a lot of information on the filtering system and even claims the file can be edited in Notepad.  Otherwise you might have to set up an AutoHotkey script that types in all your filter words for you.